# Why are roots in representation theory called roots?

Tags: representation-theory, terminology, root-systems

In the theory of root systems, I heard that roots correspond to roots of a certain characteristic polynomial, but I don't see the connection. Could someone clarify?

Comment: What literature are you using?

Comment: Compare [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154933/origin-of-the-term-weight-in-representation-theory) in which I asked where the terminology "weight" comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They give you the characteristic roots —that is, the roots of the characteristic polynomial— of the elements of the Lie algebra in their adjoint action.